# PHP warning Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on custom page template

Tags: php, errors

I have a custom built wordpress site and I am recently seeing this error.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in one of the page templates.

It is saying the warning is on this line: `foreach ($member_info->instrument as $inst) {`

Here is the code:

```
$directory = array();
foreach ($members as $member ) { // get all the user's data        
    $member_info = get_userdata($member->ID);       
    foreach ($member_info->instrument as $inst) {                
        $directory[$inst][] = array (                                
        'lastname' => $member_info->last_name,                                
        'firstname' => $member_info->first_name,                                
        'address' => $member_info->address_1,                                
        'city' => $member_info->city,                                
        'state' => $member_info->state,                                
        'zip' => $member_info->zip,                                
        'phone' => $member_info->phone,                                
        'email' => $member_info->email  ,
        'instruments' => $member_info->instrument                          
    );
```

I am researching and seeing that it needs to be in an array and I have tried changing but get formatting errors. I don't know a lot of php so any help is appreciated. The server was recently upgraded to php 5.6 so not sure if the way it is written is deprecated after that update. 
Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide us result of `var_dump($member_info);`? I suppose that `$member_info->instrument` is not an array and that cause the problem

Comment: I'm not sure how to do a var_dump? Where would I add this code? Does it go in the header of the page template file?

Comment: It's just for debugging. You can put this code into your **functions.php** file: `do_action('wp_footer',  function(){ $directory = array();
foreach ($members as $member ) { // get all the user's data        
    $member_info = get_userdata($member->ID); var_dump($member_info);
} });` **Note** you have to copy all necessary code to get this working. What `var_dump` does is displaying all the info about variable including type and size. So you can put `var_dump($member_info);` right in scope of your loop and see what is displayed on the screen

Comment: here is the codeshare, [link]https://codeshare.io/bgH9C

Comment: If this is a result of `var_dump($member_info);` you can see that `$member_info` does not have `instrument` property so `$member_info->instrument` is `NULL`. This is why you are getting this error. `NULL` is not an array

Comment: https://codeshare.io/WS4z2 this is the template page code. The page is functioning and displaying properly other than the error message. I tried removing that line and it did not display properly. here is the live page http://afm1.org/music-teacher-resource/. Maybe that will help. I'm sorry, just not sure why it is producing the error if the page is working?

Comment: Here are things you must check: **1.** Is `$members` an array? Make sure it's not `NULL`. **2.** Does `$member` has `ID` property? **3.** Is `$member_info` an object? **4.** Does `$member_info` has `instrument` property? Follow this steps one by one and when everything will be OK then it will work without errors

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two possible reason either

$member->ID is null or

this $member_info is not array

Can You give this output to us?

print_r($members)

(I would want to comment but i can't )

Comment: I am not sure how to do a print_r. Where would I put this to provide you the results? thank you for responding

Comment: just type print_r($members);die(); before foreach loop and give us a result

Comment: By the way before diving into theme or plugin development at least please learn basic php fundamentals .

Comment: I am sorry, I did not build this custom theme. It came to me seeing if it could be resolved, I apologize for my lack of knowledge on this matter.

Comment: @You don't need to apologize. Just print_r($members) before the code you gave. I mean put print_r($members) before $directory = array(); ...........